# How to use binarywriter on hashtable?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm hand-crafting a serializer in C#.

I need to write a hashtable via BinaryWriter. The problem is that the value of an entry in the hashtable can be any of int32, int64, string, double ......
I can convert anything to string and use BinaryWrite to write to a file. But how would I know the type of the value when I do BinaryRead?

One idea is to write the type of the value to the file, too. But this would be a big overhead for a large hashtable.

NB: I don't want to use binaryformatter since I'm hand-crafting.

Edit: question was closed for some reason. Apparently, I need to show some understanding of the problem. Hope this is clear enough now.

Comment: So you have a single hashtable with entries of mixed types (int32, int64, etc)? Are the keys mixed types or just the values? Do you need it to serialize quickly or is storage efficiency more important? Are all of your value entries value-types or do you have reference types / objects as well?

Comment: The keys types don't really matter. If there is a solution for values, can also apply to keys. I prefer to serialize quickly. Object or value types don't matter. I wrote a serialize method for relevant objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode both the type and the value when the type can change.  You can use some shortcuts to make the resulting file smaller, but it complicates the algorithm.

One method that would be kinda similar to how AMF prevents duplication of strings is to keep a running array of known type names.  If the type matches one of those type names, write out the array index into the next position.  If the type is a new type not yet encountered, write the new index and then the full type name as a string.

Example, given Hashtable:

```
var t = new Hashtable {
                { 'a', 1 },
                { 'b', "Two" },
                { 'c', 3 };
```

You might write this out as:

```
[char] a
[int]  0     // new integer into type array
[string] System.Int32
[int] 1
[char] b
[int] 1      // new integer into type array
[string] System.String
[string] Two
[char] c
[int] 0      // reference first element of type array, which we know is System.Int32
```

Sounds complicated, but implementation is not that difficult, but can get error prone if you mess something up along the way (which is always the case with custom binary files without clear delimiters).

Of course for Hashtable you really need to do the same for keys and values, but this gets you in the right direction for one possible solution.

Comment: This isn't a full solution (which I didn't expect) but gives direction for me to move on. Thank you very much.